# How to use one Xib and create multiple view controllers in Tab bar controller ? [Objective-C]

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xib

I have tried making multiple view controllers[here I am creating 4 view controllers] using tab bar controller in storyboard. These view controllers had multiple labels and buttons, which are different for every view controllers.

But I would like to make one Xib file and use it for other view controllers instead of making multiple view controllers in storyboard.

Note: I have seen the answers to such type of question. But they are all related to how to implement for table view cell.

Environment : Xcode 7.3 , iOS 9, Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You can create main UITabController and assign to it more than one ViewController keeping UI in one location (storyboard).

[image]